# The fastest way for connection,synchronization two android devices

Tags: android, synchronization, communication

I have to start two processes (each on different device) immediately - I mean in "the same time", second after first in time as small as possible.

What is the best (the fastest) way for sending singnal for starting process from one device to another one to get the smallest time of lags in communication? Two devices are spaced apart each other about 4-5meters.

Regards Artik

Comment: Would you always be syncing devices that are in close proximity of each other?

Comment: @Philio Yes, these two devices will be always no farther each other then 5 meters.